# Combine, Order, Dedup over Multiple Files in R

Tags: r, list, csv, unique, lapply

I have a large number of CSV files that look like this:

```
var val1 val2
a 2 1
b 2 2
c 3 3
d 9 2
e 1 1
```

I would like to:

1. Read them in
2. Take the top 3 from each CSV
3. Make a list of the variable names only (3 x number of files)
4. Keep only the unique names on the list

I think I have managed to get to point 3 by doing this:

```
csvList <- list.files(path = "mypath", pattern = "*.csv", full.names = T)

bla <- lapply(lapply(csvList, read.csv), function(x) x[order(x$val1, decreasing=T)[1:3], ])

lapply(bla,"[", , 1, drop=FALSE)
```

Now, I have a list of the top 3 variables in each CSV. However, I don't know how to convert this list to a string and keep only the unique values.

Any help is welcome.

Thank you!

Comment: So you just want `a b c` from the example? I think you can `unlist` your `lapply` result and then use `unique`, which dedups/uniqifies.

Comment: That's correct, @Frank.  I want to keep only `a b c` as a list.  `unlist` fails with `Error in structure(res, levels = lv, names = nm, class = "factor") : 
  'names' attribute [450] must be the same length as the vector [9]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is in extracting the first columns of `bla` with `drop=FALSE`. This preserves the results as a list of columns (where each row has a `name`) instead of coercing it to its lowest dimension, which is a vector. Use `drop=TRUE` instead and then `unlist` followed by `unique` as @Frank suggests:

```
unique(unlist(lapply(bla,"[", , 1, drop=TRUE)))
```

As you know, `drop=TRUE` is the default, so you don't even have to include it.

---

**Update** to new requirements in comments.

To keep the first two columns `var` and `var1` and remove duplicates in `var` (keep only the unique `var`s), do the following:

```
## unlist each column in turn and form a data frame
res <- data.frame(lapply(c(1,2), function(x) unlist(lapply(bla,"[", , x))))
colnames(res) <- c("var","var1")    ## restore the two column names
## remove duplicates
res <- res[!duplicated(res[,1]),]
```

Note that this will only keep the first row for each unique `var`. This is the definition of removing duplicates here.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Much appreciated, @aichao.  To be honest, I am new in R and completely clueless about the default options.

Comment: As a follow-up, is it possible to keep the var and val1 (first two columns), but apply unique to the first one only?

Comment: @DGenchev: please see my update. I hope that is what you are looking for.

Comment: Fantastic.  Any way I could buy you a beer?

Comment: Thanks, but no need! I'm glad to help.